# Is it possible to export just the keyframes of an animated model into COLLADA in Blender 2.8 (unbaked animation)?

Tags: animation, rigging, export

I'm trying to export a rigged model into a COLLADA file. However, it seems to bake (bake may not be the right word - I'm new to Blender) the animation in the sense that it exports every frame's joint positions / rotations (so, if the animation is playing at 30fps, and the animation is 5 seconds long, then it exports 150 different positions / rotations for each joint). I would just like to export the keyframe poses (so if there are 5 keyframes over 5 seconds, just export those 5 keyframe poses).

It seems that in Blender 2.7, the keyframes were getting exported the way that I want.

Just to illustrate my point:
I'm exporting a rigged animated model, in which the animation has 5 keyframes.
In the Blender 2.7 export, in the input section of each bone (library_animations tag), there are 5 floats (corresponding to the time value of each keyframe) and therefore 5 output matrices.

In the Blender 2.8 export, there are 250 input floats (corresponding to the time in the animation) and therefore 250 output matrices.

Is it possible to just export the keyframe poses like in Blender 2.7?

Answer (score 1):

This thing did the trick for me

[image: Exporter screenshot]